# Javascript-iframe communication

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

This is the script:

```
<script src="mysqite . com/1.js"></script>
```

It's placed on othersite . com and it display an iframe. If somebody clicks in the iframe on something, the script should write a div into othersite . com.

So my question is how to do this? I know i have read a solution somewhere 4 this be4...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have few ways:

- window.postMessage (HTML5-supported browsers only)
- Flash-based solution (not very nice, but 100% works on system with Flash installed)
- changing hash (url#hash) of iframe (it's allowed) and detecting those changes inside it.

Comment: Some examples how to catch the event? I would be interested in the 3rd solution...

Comment: @wintercounter. It's simple to check. In new browsers,you use onhashchange event of window object and in old ones you use setInterval with check. Actually, both methods are implemented, for example, in http://plugins.jquery.com/project/hashchange.